# Java InputStream read() - Android issue

Tags: java, android, networking, io

Ok I am re-writing this because people are too worried about code, and it doesn't matter.

The problem I am having is that, I can do reads from a TCP socket in a regular Java console application.

When I try to the exact same thing in Android, read() won't return. It just sits there and does nothing unless I terminate the connection between the Android client and server.

Comment: ok I guess the title doesn't make much sense, I am in a bit of a rush right now. To be clear - I am calling read() on the Android side only.

Comment: Can you show some code, please?

Comment: What protocol are you using?

Comment: I am using TCP, and sure, I will add the code

Comment: @KiithNabaal : make sure u are not doing all network related task on Main UI Thread (inside Activity)?

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in the OP

Comment: look I have to add stuff later, I am really in a rush right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it was, but once I used readLine() it worked. Maybe there was something I missed before that I noticed now, but I got it to work.

To anyone who has this problem in the future, maybe avoid read() when your server is sending text? I am not sure.

But yea, sorry JB, my code works fine. It loops infinitely by design, I was merely running a dummy program to do a test.

Answer (score 3):

Your protocol is wrong, and leads to a deadlock.

The server starts by writing a line to the client. Then it waits for a line from the client.

The client, on the other side, starts by reading from the server until there's nothing more to read, and the `read()` method return -1. This will only happen when the server closes its output stream to the client. So the client waits for the next char from the server, and the server waits for the first line from the client. Deadlock.

In general, client and server code should be symmetric. If you send a line on one side, you should read a line on the other side.

Comment: I wasn't worried about the protocol, and that is why I am reluctant to post code because people get a little too focused on the code on not the general question I ask. I am worried about why read() isn't returning. It sounds to me that read() won't return unless the server closes the output stream? This is exactly how it works?

Comment: No I am sorry, but that can't be it. I mean, I wrote a client/server to test out my code and it worked. It gave an infinite loop, but that is beside the point. The Android code doesn't even do that. I am afraid the issue might be too specific to me.

Comment: read() is a blocking call. It blocks until there is something to read. Read its API doc. It's clearly specified. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29: *This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown*